# Issue with XCA - Getting pki_x509 error when I sign

Tags: certificate, x509, openvpn, pki

I use XCA often since many years.

Since last week, I try to make new certificates to use as clients of an openVPN. All created from scratch.

When I want to sign the certificates with the CA certificate, I get this error:

```
The following error occurred:
(8pki_x509[]:certificate_name)
error:0300009C:digital envelope routines::unsupported algorithm
error:06880006:asn1::lib EVP encoding routines
error:06880006:asn1::lib EVP encryption routines
(pki_x509.cpp:582)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with XCA 2.5.0 on Windoze.
I fixed it for me by using older XCA 2.4.0.

Comment: Thank you Mr Cert. 
I hope for another solution because otherwise we are doomed to not being able to update the system, frozen in time and version

Answer (score 1):

Just updated to XCA 2.6.0 and it worked!